# sendEmailメソッドの送信元アドレス指定方法について

Tags: google-apps-script, form, gmail-api

Googleフォームの送信時に、sendEmailメソッドを使用して特定のメールアドレスに通知メールを送信するようにしています。
現在はフォーム（およびスクリプト）の作成者Aのメールアドレスから通知されているのですが、送信元のアドレスを変更することは可能でしょうか。
送信元アドレスをfromオプションを使用して設定はできましたが、フォーム送信者以外を設定したところ"ReferenceError: options is not defined"が発生してしまいます。
（フォーム送信アカウントのアドレス・エイリアスを指定できる...？）

オーナーの変更は試したのですがうまくいかず、フォーム実行者と関係のないメールアドレスから通知を送る方法についてご教示いただければと思います。

スクリプトは以下になります。

```
function sendform(e){
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var msg = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var q = item.getItem().getTitle();
    var a = item.getResponse();
    msg += q + ':' + a + '\n\n';
  }
  const options = { from: '送信元メールアドレス' };
  GmailApp.sendEmail('送信先メールアドレス', 'メール件名', msg, options);
}
```

Comment: Gmailの設定で他のメールアドレスを設定している場合、`GmailApp.getAliases()`を実行すると、使用できるメールアドレスが返されます。これを表示されているスクリプトへ使用すると、`const options = { from: GmailApp.getAliases()[0] };`などで送信者を変更してメールを送信することができます。残念ながらこの方法が質問者の求める回答かどうか不明だったため、コメントとして提案させていただきます。

Comment: @Tanaike さん
コメントありがとうございます！

いただいた方法を試したところ、フォーム作成者のエイリアスアドレスであれば送信者を変更できましたが、別アカウントのアドレスからの送信は難しいようでした...
貴重なアドバイスをいただきありがとうございました。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。`別アカウントのアドレスからの送信は難しいようでした`について、どうしてもこれを行いたい場合は、Google FormをHTMLフォームに変更して`Execute as: User accessing the web app`で`Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account`でデプロイしたWeb Appsへユーザにアクセス、およびスコープを許可させて、submit時にメールを送信するといった方法もあると思われます。ですが、ご質問の状況からは、これは想定されているものとは異なるように思われましたので、参考程度としてご理解ください。

Comment: @Tanaike さん 再度のコメントありがとうございます！
実現する方法について、追加でご教示いただきありがとうございます。こちらを参考に再度検討しようと思います。ご提案いただきありがとうございました！