# Googleフォーム送信時に特定のメールアドレス宛に通知メールを送信する際の、送信元メールアドレスを変更したい

Tags: google-apps-script, form

Googleフォームの送信時に、sendEmailメソッドを使用して特定のメールアドレスに通知メールを送信するようにしています。
現在はフォーム（およびスクリプト）の作成者Aのメールアドレスから通知されているのですが、送信元のアドレスを変更することは可能でしょうか。
フォームのオーナー変更を行なったのですが前オーナー（作成者）が送信元のままとなっており、変更する方法などありましたらご教示いただければと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

スクリプトは以下になります。

```
function sendform(e){
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var msg = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var q = item.getItem().getTitle();
    var a = item.getResponse();
    msg += q + ':' + a + '\n\n';
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail('送信先メールアドレス', 'メール件名', msg);
}
```

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/96027/ と内容が似ているように思います。
もし同じ質問なのであれば、新に質問を投稿するのではなく、既存の回答に試したことなどの追加情報を追記して下さい（この質問は削除して大丈夫です）。
もし、違う質問であれば、以前の質問との関係を少し説明いただいた方がよいと思います。